# Convert Polygon exterior ring to points and linestring to points in SQL

Tags: st-geometry

I am try create materialized views in Oracle listing a `polygon` and `linestring` vertices with their longitude and latitude in separate columns. So I know I would need to count the vertices in each polygon or linesegment but I am not having any luck on either task.

I am trying to get a loop to work to count the vertices in each object but it's not working.

```
for nn in 1..(nn-1) loop
select OBJECTID, 
SDE.st_x (SDE.st_pointn (sde.st_exteriorring (SHAPE), nn)) as X, 
SDE.st_y (SDE.st_pointn (sde.st_exteriorring (SHAPE), nn)) as Y 
from 
(SELECT sde.st_numpoints (shape) as nn from dual, SDW.trpBridge_test), SDW.trpBridge_test
order by objectid; 
end loop;
```

Comment: The `nn-1` looks wrong, since it's used to range nn (and also because the loop from 1 should be to count -- it would be from 0 to count-1)

Comment: Thank you Vince. Would changing it to 0..nn be enough?

for nn in 0..nn loop
select OBJECTID, 
SDE.st_x (SDE.st_pointn (sde.st_exteriorring (SHAPE), nn)) as X, 
SDE.st_y (SDE.st_pointn (sde.st_exteriorring (SHAPE), nn)) as Y 
from 
(SELECT sde.st_numpoints (shape) as nn from dual, SDW.trpBridge_test), SDW.trpBridge_test
order by objectid; 
end loop;

Comment: I haven't PL/SQLed, but using a variable the same name as the subselection column looks like your primary issue.  The operator is 1-based,  so you got both aspects inverted.  If you actually edit the question to contain error information, it would be easier for someone too help you.